# How to plot random points in a matrix in R

Tags: r, plot

I need to plot randonmly a set of points is a 5X5 grid.
basically I need to plot a set of 2 points (can be horizontaly or verticaly), and a set of other 3 points, is a 5x5 grid.

the position of the points should be randomly attributed.

at the end it should look like something like this (i can do in a "static" code, but i cannot do it as a random atributtion)

```
 par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
 plot.new()
 plot.window(xlim = c(0.5, 5.5), ylim = c(0.5, 5.5))
 grid(nx = 5, ny = 5, col = "black", lty = "dashed")
 box(lwd = 1)
    
 # PLot points 
 points(1, 5, pch = 16, col = "blue", cex = 1.5)
 points(2, 5, pch = 16, col = "blue", cex = 1.5)
       
 points(1, 1, pch = 16, col = "pink", cex = 1.5)
 points(1, 2, pch = 16, col = "pink", cex = 1.5)
 points(1, 3, pch = 16, col = "pink", cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: Can a blue point and a pink point be in the same box?

Comment: Nope! and diagonal plotting is also not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will perform the algorithm. It does so by enumerating all possible valid pairs of blue dots (there are only 40) and valid triples of pink dots (there are only 30). It then samples a valid set of blue dots, then repeatedly samples random sets of pink dots until there are no clashes. It then uses your plotting code to draw the result:

```r
random_points <- function() {
  
  blue_pos <- cbind(c(1:20, c(1:25)[-c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)]),
                    c(6:25, c(1:25)[-c(1, 6, 11, 16, 21)]))
  
  pink_pos <- cbind(c(1:15, 1:3, 6:8, 11:13, 16:18, 21:23),
                c(6:20, 2:4, 7:9, 12:14, 17:19, 22:24),
                c(11:25, 3:5, 8:10, 13:15, 18:20, 23:25))
  
  blue <- pink <- blue_pos[sample(nrow(blue_pos), 1),]
  
  while(any(pink %in% blue)) pink <- pink_pos[sample(nrow(pink_pos), 1),]
  
  par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
  plot.new()
  plot.window(xlim = c(0.5, 5.5), ylim = c(0.5, 5.5))
  grid(nx = 5, ny = 5, col = "black", lty = "dashed")
  box(lwd = 1)
  
  for(i in 1:2)  points(1 + (blue[i] - 1) %% 5, 
                        1 + (blue[i] - 1) %/% 5, 
                        pch = 16, col = "blue", cex = 1.5)
  
  for(i in 1:3) points(1 + (pink[i] - 1) %% 5,
                       1 + (pink[i] - 1) %/% 5,
                       pch = 16, col = "pink", cex = 1.5)
}
```

Testing it out randomly 9 times gives us:

```r
par(mfrow = c(3, 3))
for(i in 1:9) random_points()
```

[image]